# How can I create generic CRUD operations in the Kendo Grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, crud, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a project with ASP MVC 5, Kendo UI, Entity Framework, and layers; however, I'm struggling with how to simplify the generic functions of **Update** and **Create**.

Generally with [Kendo UI](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing), you set the **Class/Entity type** (*ProductViewModel*) on the *Update*, *Read*, *Delete* or *Create* methods:

```
public ActionResult Editing_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> products)
```

Nevertheless, I am updating a bunch of **Dictionaries** (Status, BarCodes, Countries, among others). I have at least 10 dictionaries, which share the same structure (**ID**, **Name** and **IsEnabled**), and the only difference is the **Table name**. I wrote some code to try to generalize the Update and Create processes, but I couldn't call them.

This is my **View**:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<Example.Business.Status>)Model.statusData)
        .Name("gridStatus")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
            columns.Bound(p => p.IsEnabled).Title("Enable");
        })
        .ToolBar(toolBar =>
        {
            toolBar.Create();
            toolBar.Save();
        })
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
        .Scrollable()
        .Pageable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(20)
            .ServerOperation(true)
            .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(p => p.ID);
                    model.Field(p => p.isActive).DefaultValue(true);
                })
            .Create(create => create.Action("Generic_Create", "Dictionaries"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("Generic_Update", "Dictionaries"))
        )
    )
```

These are the functions that I try to generalize:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Generic_Update<T>([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<T> genericData)
    {
        if (statusData != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var status in genericData)
            {
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Generic_Create<T>([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<T> genericData)
    {
        var results = new List<T>();

        if (genericData != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var generic in genericData)
            {
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

The main challenge is: how can I call/set the generic Create or Update methods from the View?

```
.Create(create => create.Action("Generic_Create", "Dictionaries"))
.Update(update => update.Action("Generic_Update", "Dictionaries"))
```

In the **Action** method, I couldn't find an option to set the Class/Entity type (Status, Countries, BarCode, etc.). Thanks for any advice or help.

Comment: Check out Telerk's [documentation](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-inline) for inline-editing.

Comment: Hi @Supersnake, I'm using this one: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing, because it's how my one is working.